# How to return interval as a ISO8601 duration?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a query:

```
SELECT max(ended_at) - min(started_at)
FROM test_run
```

How would I return the result as a [ISO8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)?

i.e. If time different is 5 seconds, I would I expect the response to be `PT5S`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT

Comment: I saw that, but I wasn't able to figure out how to actually use it in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [IntervalStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) to the desired format:

```
SET IntervalStyle to iso_8601; -- can be done in the config file as well

SELECT INTERVAL '5 seconds';
```

Result: PT5S

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot do it two queries. To clarify, I could it if I started an explicit transaction, but this would result in 4 roundtrips instead of 1 in what is a critical rendering path.

Comment: You can change this setting also in the configuration file, on database level, user level and connection level.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is basically just a format conversion with specific output format. You can achieve this, in a single trip to the server by creating function which sets the `InstervalStyle` the echos back the input value. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MkuxS6pi))

```
create or replace function iso_interval_format(interval_in interval) 
   returns interval 
  language plpgsql 
as $$
begin 
     set IntervalStyle to iso_8601;
     return interval_in; 
end;
$$;
```

Caution: If working strictly with dates be sure to cast them to `timestamp` - at least one of them.

Answer (score -2):

For my particular use case, I was able to do it as:

```
SELECT 'PT' || ceil(extract(epoch from max(ended_at) - min(started_at))) || 'S'
FROM test_run
```

Comment: This only works for seconds, from the epoch, not for any other interval. And it results in a string, not in interval. Try a + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' and you won't get a result.

Comment: That is not even correct. `PT3600S` is equal to 1 hour. Each interval segment can overflow.